# Find duplicates in multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find if there are duplicates in 2 sheets.

Example 1 (This works for this sheet):

```
Function FindDuplicate(factnr) As Boolean

    With Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("D6:D206")

        Set C = .Find(factnr, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not C Is Nothing Then
            FindDuplicate = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    End With

    FindDuplicate = False
End Function
```

Example 2 (this is what I want to accomplish [mock code], the function checking two sheets)

```
Function FindDuplicate(factnr) As Boolean

   With Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("D6:D206") & ("Sheet 2").Range("D6:D206")

     Set C = .Find(factnr, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
     If Not C Is Nothing Then
         FindDuplicate = True
         Exit Function
     End If
   End With

   FindDuplicate = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't join ranges like that, you need to search each seperately

```
Function FindDuplicate(factnr) As Boolean

 With Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("D6:D206") 

     Set C = .Find(factnr, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
     If Not C Is Nothing Then
        FindDuplicate = True
        Exit Function
      End If
End With
     With Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("D6:D206")

     Set C = .Find(factnr, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
     If Not C Is Nothing Then
        FindDuplicate = True
        Exit Function
      End If
End With


FindDuplicate = False
End Function
```